# Set a correct scale for a logarithmic graph

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I generated a graph from a CSV data which represents `T(n)`, that is, the time taken - in `milliseconds` - to execute a sort task as the data `n` increases. The graph generated can see below:

[image: Merge sort running]

I generated it with this code (assuming `merge` is a list of pairs of numbers):

```
ListLinePlot[merge, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{"tamanho entrada(n)", "tempo(ms)"}
```

My question is: how to put evidence to the fact that the growing time is actually `n*log(n)` instead of a linear time, as can be misleading by looking at the line of the graph?

Also worth noting that my data looks like this: `{{data,time},{10,0},{20,0},{30,0},{40,0},{50,0},{60,0},{70,0},{80,0},{90,0},{100,0}}...`

Comment: [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html) maybe?

Comment: Perfect! How could I have missed that? I thought that such function didn't exist and I went directly to the LogPlot.

Comment: Well, it's not perfect because the scale is logarithmic, not linearithmic. But perhaps it's good enough for you. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, all the sort methods I'm dealing with are linear arithmetic, but, it does shows the correct behavior of the algorithm at a glance on the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *almost* correct function in *Mathematica* to display this graph with that kind of data is to use as already mentioned by AccidentalFourierTransform [ListLogPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html).

After the use of the function the graph looks better, although not linear arithmetic it serve my purposes with few adjustments.

[image]

The code used to generate such graph is:

```
ListLogPlot[merge, Joined->True]
```

Comment: Note also `ListLogLogPlot` and `ListLogLinearPlot`.

Comment: Worth mentioning as well. Thanks again!